# Range of four variable under two constraints

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we are given that $a+b+c+d = 18$ and $ab + bc + cd + da + ac + bd = 24$ , is it possible to find range of $a,b,c,d$ ? Like i have solved a three variable one where we do elimination of one variable and form a quadratic with the rest two and then discriminant to be $\geq 0$ range of all three would be same. But here what we will do ?

Comment: We have $a^2\leq a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=(a+b+c+d)^2 - 2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd) =18^2-2\cdot 24$.

Comment: How will we show that that will give the all values possible , i mean there might be some more strong inequality exist which gives more wide/shorter range ? @Jochen

Comment: Of course, it only shows, that the set of solutions $(a, b, c, d)$ is bounded.

Comment: Yeah then proper way to solve it ?